# Store multiple values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have two tables in my SQLite database. On table called `movies` and a table called `trailers`. The movie table has a few columns,

```
create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "release_date"
  t.string   "image"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.string   "movie_id"
  t.string   "imdb_rating"
end
```

I want to add trailers to my movies. I've tried that by adding a column called `trailers` into my `movies` table, and then store multiple results in 1 column. But that didn't look like the right way to go.

So I've created the `trailers` table.

```
create_table "trailers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "movie_id"
  t.string   "link"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

My idea was to save every trailer link with the movie_id value so I maybe I could merge the two tables in 1 JSON file that I could use in my Angular app.

To retrieve the trailer data I've created a service,

```
service.trailer = function(youtube_link){
  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + youtube_link + '/videos?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942***a28d7cadad4&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  )
};
```

The data returned from that service looks like this,

```
{"id":157336,"results":[
  {"id":"53db3c790e0a26189a000d09","iso_639_1":"en","key":"ePbKGoIGAXY","name":"Trailer 3","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"550df44b9251413554004d43","iso_639_1":"en","key":"KlyknsTJk0w","name":"Own it today","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"533ec6fcc3a3685448009ccc","iso_639_1":"en","key":"nyc6RJEEe0U","name":"Teaser","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"5376ab510e0a26141c0005a8","iso_639_1":"en","key":"zSWdZVtXT7E","name":"Trailer","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"545da247c3a3685362005187","iso_639_1":"en","key":"Lm8p5rlrSkY","name":"Trailer 2","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"}
]}
```

So now I'm trying to save the data into the `trailer` table.

```
var mappedData = dataYoutube.results.map(function(r) {
  var obj = {}
  obj["movie_id"] = dataYoutube.id;
  obj["link"] = r.key
  return obj;
});
console.log(mappedData);

createTrailer.create({
  movie_id: mappedData.movie_id,
  link:     mappedData.key
})
```

And the createTrailer function in my service,

```
app.factory('createTrailer', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    create: function(trailer){
      return $http.post('/trailers.json', trailer);
    }
  };
}])
```

On the Rails backend I've created the routes,

```
resources :trailers, only: [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]
```

A trailers_controller.rb

```
class TrailersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_with Trailer.all
  end
  def create
  end
end
```

And a trailer_model.rb

```
class Trailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Currently when I do the save action I get an error in my rails console,

```
Started POST "/trailers.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-04 16:04:25 +0100
Processing by TrailersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"movie_id"=>[{"movie_id"=>210577, "link"=>"Ym3LB0lOJ0o"}], "link"=>[{"movie_id"=>210577, "link"=>"Ym3LB0lOJ0o"}], "trailer"=>{"movie_id"=>[{"movie_id"=>210577, "link"=>"Ym3LB0lOJ0o"}], "link"=>[{"movie_id"=>210577, "link"=>"Ym3LB0lOJ0o"}]}}
  User Load (10.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 17.1ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template trailers/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/alucardu/sites/movieseat/app/views"
  * "/home/alucardu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
):
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Angular doesn't work with database tables, and you appear to have multiple keys for a single id.

Comment: I need to use Angular to create the save function for the database.

Comment: again, angular doesn't talk with the database.  it runs in the browser, the database runs on the server.

Comment: So you are saying you don't need a Angular function to tell what data to save in the database?

Comment: no, I'm saying, for the 3rd time, that Angular itself does not communicate with a database.  you cannot execute commands to read tables, write tables, or any database functions.  Angular communicates with a web server of some sort, which would in turn handle database access.

Comment: I've never claimed that Angular communicates with a database directly.

Comment: you haven't mentioned which database technology you are using, or which web server you are using, so it's not evident at all what your function would do.  And for the record, you did in fact, multiple times, claim that you "need to use angular to create the save function for the database", which implies that you expect angular to talk to the database.

Comment: I honestly want to help.  In order to do that, I think we need to be on the same page about what it is you are actually trying to accomplish.  I think *possibly* the map function in the answer may be what you were asking for, but if not, I can only ask for some clarity in the question.

Comment: You have one table or two tables? Because, you said you've created a table called `trailers` and you want to store each result  into my `trailer` table. Also, what do you mean result in this sentence? A result after search or a result after add movie action happens?

Comment: @Claies I thank you for your patience. I've updated my question quite a lot to hopefully give more understanding of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data above, you can make that an array of objects, each object having the `movie_id` and `link` column:

```
var mappedData = data.results.map(function(r) {
    var obj = {}
    obj["movie_id"] = data.id;
    obj["link"] = r.key

    return obj;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/muat8brp/